# Very slow response from action creator React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am getting super slow response times (upwards 10 seconds) for a function to be called in my action creator.

```
export function acceptContract(id) {
  return function(dispatch) {

    const config = { headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('etherToken') } };
    const data = { data: id };

    axios.put('/pending-contracts/accept', 
      data,
      config
    ).then( response => {
        console.log(response);
        getPendingContracts();
      })
      .catch( response => {
        // If the get doesn't work, boot the user out to index.
        console.log(response);
      });

  }
}
```

I update one of the values of contracts in my DB, and I want redux to then dispatch the new list for the user to show the update on the UI.

Not sure why the getPendingContract() invocation takes so long. I get the response from my backend almost immediately.

```
export function getPendingContracts() {
  return function(dispatch) {

    axios.get('/pending-contracts', {
      headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('etherToken') }
    })
    .then( response => {
      console.log('in getPendingContracts')
      return dispatch({
        type: PENDING_CONTRACTS_LIST,
        payload: response.data.message
      });
    })
    .catch( response => {
      // If the get doesn't work, boot the user out to index.
      console.log(response);
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be related to how you are calling `getPendingContracts` from `acceptContract`.  You are just calling the function directly, without dispatching it. As far as i can tell all that would do is return you a function that never gets invoked, not sure how you get a response at all. Change the call to this:

```
then( response => {
    console.log(response);
    dispatch(getPendingContracts());
})
```

Comment: Yeah, that got the behaviour I expected. How odd it gave me a delayed response at all.